# Select correct button when two buttons share the same class

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<a class="action_btn recommend_btn" act="recommend" href="recommend.php">
    Recommend
</a>
```

and my jQuery is:

```
$(".action_btn").click(function() {

});
```

the problem is that I have another

```
<a class="save action_btn" onclick="return false;">
    Save
</a>
```

but I don't want this button to trigger this click function.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use the other selector?

```
$(".recommend_btn").click(function() { /* code */});
```

Or you could filter the second one out (if you want to trigger that function on all `.action_btn` elements, but not `.save` elements:

```
$(".action_btn").not(".save").click(function() { /* code */});
```

Comment: @user721937 Either that or use the id attribute which is designed to be unique.

Comment: @Marty: I am usually trying to not modify provided HTML, unless necessary or explicitly allowed. But that's also an option of course.

Comment: Fair enough - just seems strange to me for someone to be selecting something by class if it's unique.

Comment: But we don't know if it's unique. And I assume that it isn't just because he used class for it.

Comment: not sure if your :not will work as you've written it as the space between the class and not means where decendant does not have a class of save. You want $(".action_btn:not('.save')").click(function() { /* code */}); Also the jQuery API documentation recoments the use of the not() method over the :not() selector

Comment: @Jon P: Indeed, it didn't. I alrady changed that. But thanks for pointing that out anyway, I was curious why it didn't work as expected. Didn't saw that major difference in space :)

Answer (score 0):

You can select based on multiple conditions, so elements of class "action_btn" having an attribute "href" with a value of "recommend.php":

```
$('.action_btn[href="recommend.php"]').click(function(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a specific element by adding an ID to that element since ID is unique to all.

you html would look like this

```
 <a class="action_btn recommend_btn" id="recommentBtn" act="recommend" href="recommend.php">Recommend</a>
```

and jquery is

```
 $("#recommentBtn").click(function() { /* code */});
```

or if you want class only you can do like this for you current html

```
$(".action_btn.recommend_btn").click(function() { /* code */});
```

the later will only look for the element with the both class.

Answer (score 0):

To Select all action_btn except those with a save class use the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
$(".action_btn").not(".save").click(function() {

    });
```